# How to tell shiny server and rstudio server which version of R to use?

Tags: rstudio, rstudio-server

I have R 3.6 and 4.0 installed. When I run R from terminal it is 4.0. However shiny server and rstudio server are running 3.6.

I added to `/etc/rstudio/rserver.conf` this

```
rsession-which-r=/opt/R/4.0.2/lib/R/bin/R
```

Which is obviously where R 4.0 lives.

But I’m still getting 3.6 when I open r studio in the browser.

There is no slot in global options for which R versions to use. Only “default working directory”.

What gives?

Answer (score 0):

You can select the R-Version in the upper right corner:

[image]

The selected Version in Server will automatically be used in Connect

Comment: It is not there 

Comment: Have you checked the following: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/226872207-Managing-R-versions-in-RStudio-Connect?mobile_site=true