# what R version is used when deploying a shiny app to shinyapps.io?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I have started deploying some apps on [shinyapps.io](https://www.shinyapps.io/). as we had an example recently of an older app that did not run with the latest R versions, I have been wondering what R version is used on shinyapps.io. I have found info about package sources and how these are inferred and even on compatible python versions in the [documentation](https://docs.rstudio.com/shinyapps.io/getting-started.html#working-with-shiny-for-r), and there is some information about R versions with [posit/Rstudio connect](https://support.posit.co/hc/en-us/articles/226872207-Managing-R-versions-in-RStudio-Connect). However, I have not found anything about R versions on shinyapps.io. How can I check what R version is being used? and is there any way to set it to a specific version?

Comment: Make a simple app that prints `sessionInfo()`

Comment: This comment says "You can select the R-Version in the upper right corner:

enter image description here

The selected Version in Server will automatically be used in Connect" https://stackoverflow.com/a/63884858/10276092

Comment: Current release version

Comment: I do not see anything to select an R version as in the linked comment. I could write an app to print the session info... as per Iz100's comment, it seems to be the most recent one, assuming there is no way for me to change it

Answer (score 0):

Apps on [shinyapps.io](https://shinyapps.io) run on the currently released version of R. Have a look at the [R Sources page](https://cran.r-project.org/sources.html) on CRAN to see what the current version is.

You cannot set R to a specific version. For that, Posit (previously RStudio) provides enterprise solutions such as [Posit Connect](https://www.rstudio.com/products/connect/).